# Apache rewrite to ignore certain directory and all its contents

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for the rewrite rule for mod_rewrite in Apache so that when asking for a specific subdirectory, it and all its contents gets redirected to another location.

I currently have the following:

```
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule    ^/SUBDIRECTORY(/.*)?  /another/location
```

But this only manages to redirect /SUBDIRECTORY requests to the desired location, while all others (like (/SUBDIRECTORY/ , /SUBDIRECTORY/anything/else ) gets me an error telling me that the redirection is not valid... The error is

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)
```

as if the redirections loops themselves...

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try it without the question mark?

```
RewriteRule ^/somepath(.*) /another/location
```

Edit: I wonder if its just hitting some sort of loop, maybe try external redirection

```
RewriteRule    ^/SUBDIRECTORY(/.*)  /another/location [R]
```

Comment: nope... this throws me the same error as before... BTW I'm using Apache 2.2, and if I add a RewriteLog it doesn't writes anything to it :/ neither to error_log ... The error is a 310 Error (to many redirections)

Comment: that's it! the R flag fixed the problem... Thanks!